# How to read a file on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to code my C# Xamarin app to open and read files on the device. I'm used to working on Windows.

Since I can't use the debugger I've added some MakeToast() lines so I know that the code at least reached a certain point:

```
       try
        {
            var fileName = "jason.txt";
            MakeToast(fileName);
            var testFile = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, fileName);
            MakeToast(testFile);
            MakeToast("102");
            if (testFile.Length > 0)
            {
                MakeToast("103");
                string content;
                AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
                MakeToast("1033");
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open(testFile)))

                {
                    MakeToast("104");
                    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    txtOriginal.Text = content;
                     
                }
                if (content != null) MakeToast("105");
                else MakeToast("null content"); 
            }
            else
                MakeToast("File Length 0");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MakeToast(ex.Message);
        }
```

The code gets to MakeToast("1033") but no further. No errors occur (AFAIK). I don't see "104" or "105".

I would just like to let the user read data in the Documents folder and, hopefully, other folders.

Comment: Are you trying to read an asset or a file?

Comment: trying to read a file

Comment: Then don’t use AssetManager, just use normal System.IO classes

Comment: I just found that. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can load the Files Embedded as Resources.

Then, you can use the `System.IO.StreamReader` to read the file.

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(LoadResourceText)).Assembly;
    Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.LibTextResource.txt");
    string text = "";
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream))
    {  
        text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The debugger now works. There is a switch on the phone: wait for debugger (duh!) and it was on. I never noticed it before. Anyway, now it debugs normally.